# Using commas within textbox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

If I use the following code for my textbox, when I enter the number `1,000,000` and submit it with my command button it shows up in Range("F1IMPG1") as `1`.

```
Range("F1IMPG1").Value = Val(txtF1IMP1.Value)
```

If I don't use commas it shows up correctly as `1,000,000`.

Anybody know why this might be?

Answer (score 1):

That is because **VAL()** stops at the first comma.  See *VBA Help*

Comment: CLng() or CDbl() are probably what you want to use in this situation.